# How to use work week in DateField in Django admin

Tags: django

In my model, I say:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
   start = models.DateField(help_text='Start Date')
```

In the django admin, when adding a new Foo object, I see a text field with a calendar attached allowing me to select the date. I want to customize this a little bit so that I can either select the date from the calendar or enter something like `WW12'22` in the textfield and during `Save`, this gets converted into a DateField. I am not sure how to do implement this in the django admin. Any ideas would be helpful.

I try something like this, but I get an invalid date when I enter '05 22' (i.e, WW05'22).

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
     start_date = forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(format='%W %y'), localize=True)
```

Comment: It's possible to parse a date using the week number but you would need to include the day of the week in your input too, is that okay?

Comment: Thanks for the help. No, the user requirement is just to enter week and year. maybe in the clean() form we can artificially add the day of the week to be set to 'Monday' before we pass is it for parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own `DateField` subclass and when the provided value isn't parsed as a date you implement your own parsing.

Since you need to provide the day of the week to use week number when parsing, replace the "WW" part of your input with `1` and parse this as the day of the week (`1` is Monday)

admin.py

```
import re
import datetime

from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms

from .models import Foo
from django.contrib.admin.widgets import AdminDateWidget

class MyDateField(forms.DateField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        try:
            return super().to_python(value)
        except forms.ValidationError:
            if re.match(r'WW\d+\'\d+', value):
                return datetime.datetime.strptime(value.replace('WW', '1-'), '%w-%W\'%y')
            raise


class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):

    start_date = MyDateField(widget = AdminDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = '__all__'


class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = FooForm


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, made a minor edit to add `widget=AdminDateWidget` to get the date widget back into the form. This works as intended now.

Comment: Any idea how to make this work if I use `list_editable` in `FooAdmin`? For some reason, it works fine for a single model, but if I try to edit multi items on the admin page. it ignores `MyDateField` and uses `DateField` instead.